# mvc3 dapper parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, dapper

I have dapper working correctly, but it is unsecure as in I haven't been using parameters, how can I best turn my dapper variables into parameters for instance this is the unparameterized code that I had that worked..

```
var getinfo = sqlConnection.Query<test>("Select name,location from tests where location="+ myplace).FirstOrDefault();
```

**myplace** is a textbox that users put information on, now when I tried to parameterized that code like

```
var getinfo = sqlConnection.Query<test>("Select name,location from tests where location='@location'", new {location = myplace}).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get absolutely no returns back, yet no error messages. What can I be missing here or whats the best way to parameterized variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to place the single quotes around the parameter.  Hope this helps.

```
var getinfo = sqlConnection.Query<test>("Select name,location from tests where location=@location", new {location = myplace}).FirstOrDefault();
```